# Is it possible to setup a D-Link DIR-300 rev D1 wifi router as repeater?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a D-Link DIR-300 rev D1 and looking in admin menu looks like it can be used as repeater, but It don't work and I don't understand why
I have setup up it like this

1. Go to Wireless network settings wizard and selected Client
   [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9zA4.png) and connect to my another router with Wifi and Internet Access
2. Set WAN settings like this so I get IP 192.168.1.190 from another my router with gateway 192.168.1.1 internet and DNS 8.8.8.8
   [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ha0U.png)

3.[Settings>Net>Wan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aakQl.png)

So now it looks like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVOip.png)

I tried to ping 192.168.1.1 from admin menu but packets are loss

I googled and all that I found is all people are saying to flash DD-WRT to configure it as a repeater, but it's only rev A1 is supported

Is it possible to configure D-Link DIR-300 rev D1 as repeater or to make him take Wifi from another network and share internet by LAN ?

If yes, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Read this:  https://www.screenbeam.com/wifihelp/wifibooster/differences-wifi-booster-wifi-extender-wifi-repeater/#:~:text=As%20the%20name%20implies%2C%20wireless,response%20time%2C%20is%20typically%20increased.   ...  and see if your router will work like this.

Answer (score 0):

Repeater mode is straight-forward
[on the DIR-612 router](https://www.dlink.com.my/how-to-setup-repeater-mode-on-my-dir-612-router/).

[image]

If your firmware does not support this option, and if it's
updated to the latest version, then you will need an alternate
third-party firmware.

In this case, you could use the DD-WRT firmware.
You will find some instructions for doing so in the article
[Connecting dir 300 as a repeater](https://royalprice.ru/en/overview-windows/podklyuchenie-dir-300-kak-repiter-nastroika-wifi-povtoritelya-repitera-dlya/)

Comment: This option is missing. There is only option from my 1st screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9zA4.png
I think DD-WRT will brick my router because only Rev. D1 is not supported. There is only version for A1 and B1. Which one I should use ?

Comment: Did you say that "Access point" mode doesn't help?

Comment: They name it Access point and it's pretty confusing. Actually description of Access point says _Select this item if you want to connect a portable device to the Internet via Wi-Fi_ so that's not what I need. This is regular configuration receiving internet via LAN/WAN cable and seed Wi-Fi. What I need is Client and Connect to a existing Wi-Fi network as client and repeat this Wi-Fi network and receive internet from this router to other computers through LAN(if that is possible)

Comment: Have you tried this mode (it's basically your only hope)? I have found in the DD-WRT router database an entry for [D-Link DIR-300 A1](https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/?model=DIR-300_A1). I suppose the A1 is different from D1?

Comment: yes, they are different as I read. There are also firmware for B1. And OpenWRT firmware for other revisions, but no firmware for D1

Comment: I gave also searched the firmware [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/toh/start?dataflt%5BBrand*%7E%5D=d-link), and unfortunately no firmware for your model. Some routers are too hard to install a non-stock firmware, and yours seems one of them.